# How to set and capture unchecked and checked checkboxes in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox

In the above code i want to display initial state of checkboxes as mentioned in `initialstatus` array in UI and then I may change randomly any checkbox in `initialStatus` .. which should be reflected in `initialstatus` array.

```
 <div class="container" [hidden]="submitted">
       <form   ng-app="app" (submit)="onSubmit()">
      <div *ngFor="let initial of initialState,let j = index" >
    <div *ngIf="initial.checked==true">
     <button class="button" type="button">Device{{j}} </button>
       &nbsp; 
       <label class="switch">
         <input type="checkbox" name= "checked" id="checkbox_category" checked    />
        <div class="slider round"></div>
      </label>
       <br/> 
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="initial.checked==false">
       <button class="button" type="button">Device{{j}}</button>
       &nbsp; 
       <label class="switch">
         <input type="checkbox"  id="checkbox_category" name= "checked"   />
        <div class="slider round"></div>
      </label>
       <br/> 
       </div>
    </div>
    <button class="buttons" type="submit">Submit</button>

    <button (click)="resetAll()">Reset</button>
    <button (click)="selectAll()">selectALL</button>
    </form>

    </div>
```

Component :

```
export class DashboardComponent{

submitted:boolean;
 model= new SendDetails();

  initialState:any = [{checked:true},{checked:false},{checked:true},{checked:false},{checked:true},{checked:false}];

  intendedDeviceStatus: any = this.initialState;

   constructor(
    ) {
        this.submitted=false;
        }

  onSubmit(){
      this.submitted=true;
      this.model.initSession();

  }

resetAll() {
  this.initialState.forEach((initial:any) => {
   initial.checked = false;
  }
)}
selectAll() {
  this.initialState.forEach((initial:any) => {
   initial.checked = true;
  }
)}
}
}
```

But its not happening ....I'm able to show initial status separately and any changes made in UI are reflected back in Array.
        To achieve  `InitialStatus` display my input tag is mentioned as above  and to achieve two way binding i need to add `ngModel` into my input tag
    in my input tag.But I'm unable to achieve both at same time. How to achieve two way binding and displaying some check boxes as checked and few as unchecked.

Comment: check this if it helps. [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VLDhT5LILPnOyyilFbVp?p=preview), but i gues this is an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7329)

Answer (score 1):

input type="checkbox" checked={{initial.checked}} . This will set the initial checked state as true or false depending on what you have in your array. When user changes that will also be reflected in the array that you are repeating.

Comment: Im unable to get initialstatus of checkboxes as mentioned by you answer @RemyaJ

Comment: Set this.initialstate as your array and iterate as mentioned in my ans.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this all by just one loop

Template :

```
<form (submit)="register()">
            <div *ngFor="let initial of initialState,let j = index" >
                <button class="button" type="button">Device{{j}} </button>
                &nbsp; 
                <label class="switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" name= "checked[{{j}}]" [(ngModel)]='initialState[j].checked'/>
                <div class="slider round"></div>
                </label>
                <br/> 
            </div>
            <button class="buttons" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Component :

```
initialState:any = [{'checked':true},{'checked':false},{'checked':true},{'checked':false},{'checked':true},{'checked':false}];

register()
{
  console.log(this.initialState);
}
```

Changed `initialState:any` a little bit.

For your [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/gDo3OLM4PIseJFgnLv1k?p=preview) just change this line:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checked" [checked]='initialState[j].checked' (change)='initialState[j].checked = $event.target.checked' />
```

You can also check it here : [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/gDo3OLM4PIseJFgnLv1k?p=preview)

Comment: Im unable to get initialstatus of checkboxes as mentioned by you answer @Vivek Doshi

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: @VivekDoshi : are you sure it works like this with [(ngModel)]? see this  [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7329), also I created [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/EKhJ2efzbibdeNAhu8EA?p=preview)

Comment: Yes I am 100% sure , I have tested this and after that posted here and I have also used this method in my projects , still find no issues.

Comment: could you please correct the issue in [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/EKhJ2efzbibdeNAhu8EA?p=preview), as it doesn't show up checkbox state checked?

Comment: can't see use of `ngModel`in your plunker. by `(change)` event it is always possible. but not by `[(ngModel)]='initialState[j].checked'`

Comment: Dont its not working on plunker , but working on my machine ,

Comment: Using this :


  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",


And its working 100% fine.